# Can I execute nodejs javascript scripts in chrome devtools?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, terminal, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to use **chrome devtools** to execute the terminal command `node myfile.js`, so the chrome console would output all `console.log`s from my code?
I have got some *terminal* plugin installed in my IDE and I use some keyboard shortcuts when I want to run this command on my files, to get my logs immediately *(like when running html+js in the browser)* but it prints out just plain text. Chrome can recognize the output data type and structurize it well *(arrays, objects)*, what is really cool.

I've already tried out `node inspect-brk` but its purpose seems to be quite different than just printing out my logs.

**UPDATE:**

I've found very interesting [link](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/11769/node-js-console-debugger-for-windows) with npm modules that do what I mean.

I have alredy tested `node-monkey` but it does not work on my Windows, but `iron-node` works great and I can run my `.js` files with `iron-node file.js` command and get all `console.log`s in Chrome devtools!

Comment: No, it's not possible, but you can use remote-debugging directly from node.js and use devtools.

Comment: *web browser* and *node.js* are completely different *host environments* in which javascript runtime gets executed in, so, no, it is not possible. Just curious why you would like to do that?

Comment: @Srle then try `iron-node`

Answer (score 5):

run your file with

```
node --inspect <your file name>.js
```

and then type in chrome

```
chrome://inspect
```

See https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html#debugger_v8_inspector_integration_for_node_js for reference

Answer (score 0):

--inspect-brk is used for breakpoint purposes, with that flag the debugger is ready to run your code  but is expecting the developer to add something before it begins to run your script. There is a play button at the top corner of the chrome devtools debugger, and if there are no other breakpoints or debugger; statments in your code it will run as it would run or your workstation