# html + js: retrieve the line number in the file where a div is created

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

I have a  html file (the path is `C:/Users/user/file.html`) composed of several blocks. Next to each title of a block I would like to have a link that looks like this `vscode://file/C:/Users/user/file.html:150:45`

This link opens my file in VsCode to the line 150 and the column 45.

Because the script will change a lot, I do not want to hard code the link as it will require too much work. So I would like to create this vscode link dynamically with a js script. I got everything sorted out, except the part that should retrieve the correct line and column number of the "selected" title in the file.

You can see what I mean in the snippet below: for instance, if in my html file, the line/column where `Title A` is "hardcoded" is 80/20, then the js script should generate the link on "edit this block" as `vscode://file/C:/Users/user/file.html:80:20`.

Also, I will create some content dynamically with another piece of js script so the line/column number in the link should reflect the "hardcoded" and not the one in the browser.

(I really care about the line, but not so much about the column number, I will be satisfied if it's always set to 1).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>

    <div>
        <a-title>Title A</a-title>
       <p>Long text for A</p> 
    </div>

    <div>
        <a-title>Title B</a-title>
       <p>Long text for B</p> 
    </div>


    <div>
        <a-title>Title C</a-title>
       <p>Long text for C</p> 
    </div>

    <script>
        //  get all existing div in document
        var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("a-title");

        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            var atitle = elements[i];
            var atitle_innerHtml = atitle.innerHTML;
            atitle.innerHTML = atitle_innerHtml +" <a href=\"vscode://file/C:/Users/user/file.html:150:45\">edit this block</a>";
        };
    </script>
   
</body>
```

Comment: You'll need to write a Visual Studio Code extension for that. The DOM won't know that information, since it works off of the DOM tree, where white space is collapsed...

Comment: @HereticMonkey, there is no way I can do that by having a js script loading the file (just like it would for a .txt file) and the doing a search in it lin by line, or something like that?

Comment: i agree to @HereticMonkey since the DOM tree will not preserve such information for good reason. even inline javascript will not give you proper line numbers (if any)

Comment: the best you can do is parse the file as a string and count the lines... but there's no really way to match which element belongs on which line since it's just not part of the DOM.  Plus, you are adding elements dynamically, which can potentially also change the line numbers as well, so it would get confusing really fast.

Comment: Well, the question is, how badly do you need these links? If you're at the point of trying to reverse-engineer the browser to get that information, you may want to look at whether what you're trying to do makes sense...

Comment: @ChrisBarr, this is a good idea:  I could actually split the parsed file right at the title I want, and then count the line break. This will give me the line number.  Do you think it can work?

Comment: It will tell you how many lines there are... but being able to correctly match up a line with a particular HTML element is the challenge, unless you already know this or you have the same number of lines as you do elements.  Either way it seems like a huge unreliable hack.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, I thought quite a lot about my setup and I could find a better way of doing it. Basically I will regularly add new blocks in my file and I will soon have 100+ of them. Displaying them in an html file allow me to get a nice display with hidden/toggle blocks. But I also need to be able to edit each block easily, the reason why I am trying to get this vscode link with line number

Comment: You could add a `data` attribute with the line number manually each time you add a new block. Then you can get it using javascript. It will be really messy to maintain, so you may think of using some serverside language to populate the line number when the final HTML is rendered (like using the `__LINE__` magic constant on PHP or Ruby for example)

Comment: @MagTun if you want to be precise you'll need something to process the file and add the data (I think PHP would be the easiest one, just add `data-line="<?php echo __LINE__; ?>` on each div tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going the way @arieljuod proposed but because I am not using my file on a server I didn't go with `PHP`.

I was using `AHK` anyway to start my html file with a shortcut so it didn't take much to start instead a Python script that create/replace a data-line attribute and start the `html` file.

```
import re  #regex to replace number line 
import webbrowser
matchtitle="<a-title"
data_line=" data-line="
all_lines_as_list=[]
filename=r"C:\Users\Me\memo python.html"

with open(filename, "r", encoding="utf8") as myFile_read:
    for num, line in enumerate(myFile_read, 0):
            # print (num, line)
            if matchtitle in line or matchpre in line:
                # print(line)
                if data_line in line:
                    line = re.sub(r"\d+", str(num+1), line)
                else:
                    line=line.replace(matchtitle, matchtitle+data_line+f"\"{num+1}\" ")
            all_lines_as_list.append(line)
    all_lines_joined="".join(all_lines_as_list)
    # print(all_lines_joined)
    with open(filename, "w", encoding="utf8") as myFile_write:
        myFile_write.write(all_lines_joined)


new=2 # open html file in a new browser file
webbrowser.open(filename,new=new)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative approach which is fairly simple:

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

const options = { includeNodeLocations: true };

// can use a string, url or file here
JSDOM.fromFile("./jsdomTest.html", options).then(dom => {

  const aTitles = dom.window.document.getElementsByTagName("a-title");

  for (let element of aTitles) {

    // console.log(dom.nodeLocation(element).line);
    // console.log(dom.nodeLocation(element).endTag.col);

    element.innerHTML += ` <a href=\"vscode://file/C:/Users/user/file.html:${dom.nodeLocation(element).line}:${dom.nodeLocation(element).endTag.col}\">edit this block</a>`;    
  };

  console.log(dom.window.document.documentElement.innerHTML);
  // write to a file
});
```

The [jsdom package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom) will allow you to easily query for elements.  Its option `includeNodeLocations` will save the original locations (line numbers and columns and more) of any element.

The code above will produce this console.log:

```
<head></head><body>

    <div>
        <a-title>Title A <a href="vscode://file/C:/Users/user/file.html:5:25">edit this block</a></a-title> 
       <p>Long text for A</p> 
    </div>

    <div>
        <a-title>Title B <a href="vscode://file/C:/Users/user/file.html:10:25">edit this block</a></a-title>
       <p>Long text for B</p> 
    </div>

    <div>
        <a-title>Title C <a href="vscode://file/C:/Users/user/file.html:16:25">edit this block</a></a-title>
       <p>Long text for C</p> 
    </div>
```

Comment: That's a nice solution but it requires to install node.js. I use my file as s simple .html file that I preview locally in Chrome browser and [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46115391/can-i-execute-nodejs-javascript-scripts-in-chrome-devtools) turning it into a node.js app would be quite cumbersome.    IN any case, it may help someone else!

Comment: Yes, I added it mainly for others to see since you already had a solution and I wasn't clear on your workflow.  The jsdom package is pretty powerful - basically simulating the dom without a browser (and the line number stuff is just a bonus).

Answer (score -1):

You can get the document source code with `document.documentElement.innerHTML;` You can then use text search to find the element of interest, and the line number.

However, as there is no way I know to get the parts that are outside the  tag, including the doctype. You will have make assumptions there.

Comment: `innerHTML` will show you the *browser's internal representation of the HTML*, not necessary what was sent in the network request. For instance, text nodes consisting of spaces and/or line breaks could be removed, rendering the line numbers incorrect relative to the source file.

Comment: yes this is a good idea. I will start with `document.body.innerHTML;`.  How would I search for the `<a-title>` inside this and get the line number

Comment: @HereticMonkey, I just did a console.log(document.body.innerHTML); (before running any script) and I get my hardcoded file, not the one dynamically created so it's a good start

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes, this will represent the current state of the html as seen by the browser. More often than not, this is also exactly the same Html fed to the browser, including tag spacing and comments. This is only an issue when you originally provided invalid HTML (the browser will forcibly try to correct the HTML).